# Replacing inside body using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, domdocument, str-replace

i am trying to replace inside body tag using PHP but every time i am getting different output than i expecting the one.

Try :

```
$homepage = "<head>https://www.example.com</head> <body>https://www.example.com</body>";
$homepage = substr($homepage, strpos($homepage, "<body>"));
$homepage = preg_replace("/https:\/\/(.?)+\.example\.com/", "https://www.example.net", $homepage);
echo $homepage;
```

Output :

```
<head>https://www.example.net</body>
```

The output i am looking for :

```
<head>https://www.example.com</head> <body>https://www.example.net</body>
```

**I just want to change/replace the string inside  tag.**

Comment: [You shouldn't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4705262).

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Then?

Comment: Use an HTML parser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70863965/php-preg-replace-only-within-body-tag

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton can you tell me. how can i use HTML parser in my code?

Comment: @JenniferAffleck You will have to look up an HTML parser and follow it's documentation.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you tell me what wrong with my code?.

Comment: Just to make sure: are you trying to change `.com` to `.net` in `<body>` but not in `<head>`?

Comment: @JackFleeting that a example URL. i am trying to change a particular string inside '<body>' tag and yes it should not affect '<head>' tag. Head tag should be remain same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split head & body
2. Replace string in body
3. Join head & body

Your regex was problematic, I assumed you wanted to catch both `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`

Here is what you are looking for:

```php
<?php

$homepage = '<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/whatever.css"></head><body>This link <a href="https://www.example.com">https://example.com</a> and this one <a href="https://www.example.com">https://www.example.com</a> will be replaced</body>';

$neck_pos = strpos($homepage, "<body");
$head = substr($homepage, 0, $neck_pos);
$body = substr($homepage, $neck_pos);


$body = preg_replace("/https:\/\/[w]*\.*example\.com/", "https://www.example.net", $body);

$homepage = $head . $body;

echo $homepage;
```

Comment: Body tag have a class which generate random. I am trying regex to match all the class `<body class=" ">` to `<body.?>` but it not working. `$neck_pos = strpos($homepage, '<body.?>');`

Comment: I've edited the answer to track the position of `<body` instead of `<body>`.

Pro tip: 
- Use [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to test your regex
- Check the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos) to respect expected parameters

Comment: Thanks for the update and suggestion. Is it possible to use `regex` with `strpos` and `substr` ?

Comment: and same if i want to make a changes to `<head>` tag then i have to use like this `$head = preg_replace("/https:\/\/[w]*\.*example\.com/", "https://www.example.net", $head);` - I am right?

Comment: Most of your questions will find answer in the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos) and by experimenting by yourself.

Comment: Machines always do what they are told to do.
It is our job as programmers to figure out what we ask for.
Split your problems into small puzzle pieces and solve them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to reiterate what you were told in the comments: don't use regex on HTML/XML - ever. Always use a parser and (preferably) xpath to do the search. Look at the example below as a first step - you WILL need to read up on the whole subject. If the HTML/XML gets more complicated, so will the search:

```
$homepage = "<head>https://www.example.com</head> <body>https://www.example.com</body>";
$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($homepage, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); 
$target= $xpath->query('//body');
$target[0]->nodeValue="https://www.example.net";
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<p>https://www.example.com <body>https://www.example.net</body></p>
```

Comment: In output `<head>` is missing. i am looking for output like `<head>https://www.example.com</head> <body>https://www.example.net</body>`